# How to select the rows when the particular column has specific number of fields with delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the below dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Cell':['cell_D1_TY_L_90','cell4_D2_TY_L_90','cell6_TY_L_90','cell2_D4_TY_L_90','cell1_L_90'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan,3], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 5, 5,np.nan], 'D6':[17, 3, np.nan,np.nan,2],'diff%':[np.nan,['D2'],['D2','D3'],['D1','D3'],['D1','D2','D6']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    Cell             D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%
0   cell_D1_TY_L_90   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN
1  cell4_D2_TY_L_90   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [D2]
2     cell6_TY_L_90   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [D2,D3]
3  cell2_D4_TY_L_90   6  NaN  5.0   NaN      [D1, D3]
4        cell1_L_90   6  3.0  NaN   2.0     [D1, D2, D6]
```

I want to create 2 things.

**1** . Style the dataframe by taking 'diff%' column specified column names & make the corresponding column  value to bold and change text color to red

Eg.  Consider row 3

```
    Cell             D1      D2     D3      D6         diff%
3  cell2_D4_TY_L_90   **6**  NaN  **5.0**   NaN      [D1, D3]
```

I want to make D1 and D3 values --> 6 and 5.0 to bold red color.

**2** . Create below 2 dataframes

```
1.dataframe with exactly 5 fields in 'Cell' column with above styling.
2.dataframe with less than 5 fields in the 'Cell' column with above styling.


    Cell             D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%
0   cell_D1_TY_L_90   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN
1  cell4_D2_TY_L_90   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [D2]
3  cell2_D4_TY_L_90   6  NaN  5.0   NaN      [D1, D3]


    Cell             D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%
2     cell6_TY_L_90   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [D2,D3]
4        cell1_L_90   6  3.0  NaN   2.0     [D1, D2, D6]
```

Please let me know any solution to this?

Comment: Your reproducible input is inconsistent with the shown example, there should be column names (`['D1', 'D3']`) not numbers (`[16.67, 50]`). Please clarify

Comment: i corrected the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
def style(x):
    if isinstance(x['diff%'], list):
        return pd.Series('color: red; font-weight: bold',
                         index=x['diff%']).reindex(x.index)
    else:
        return pd.Series(index=x.index)
    
df.style.apply(style, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Used input:

```
d = {'Cell':['cell_D1_TY_L_90','cell4_D2_TY_L_90','cell6_TY_L_90','cell2_D4_TY_L_90','cell1_L_90'],
     'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan,3], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 5, 5,np.nan],
     'D6':[17, 3, np.nan,np.nan,2],
     'diff%':[np.nan,['D2'],['D2', 'D3'],['D1', 'D3'],['D1', 'D2', 'D6']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: @sandeep you're welcome. Does it work as you want?

Comment: it always works with your solution..;)